# Validate Features in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, relationship-class, validation

In ArcMap, I can easily enforce my geodatabase relationships rules (ex. one-to-one relationships) by selecting features and selecting, in the editor toolbar, the Validate Features button. I can then have a list of features that does not meet my Relationship Class rules

[image][image]

In ArcGIS Pro, is there a similar way to do so, without requiring a Data Reviewer Licence (ArcMap's Validate Features doesn't)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I read, ArcGIS Pro's comparable Validate Features tool requires Data Reviewer. However, as a workaround/preventative measure, I would try attribute rules (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/validation-attribute-rules.htm). Attribute Rules can be used to validate spatial as well as attribute data quality. Another thing to explore is the Data Comparison toolset (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/an-overview-of-the-data-comparison-toolset.htm).